# GWT last browser

Tags: gwt, internet-explorer-9

I'm very on GWT.

I need some advice.
I have to fix an old web app that uses GWT components (version 1.x I think!).

The problem is that no longer works on newer browsers ... very fine on IE7.

In your opinion what is the problem?
What is the best way to achive my gol?

Thank you.

Comment: Is it only the layout that is messing or the application behaviour ?

Comment: What errors do you get when you try to change the GWT version to 2.4?

Comment: In my project I have this jars: gwt-servlet.jar, gwt-sl.jar, gwt-user.jar, gwt-widgets-0.1.5.jar, gwt-widgets-server-0.1.2.jar. What i have to change. In the 2.4 version there aren't so many jars! Thanks

Comment: But in general: a GWT app (whith an old version) is no longer available in new browsers. Is always necessary to update the app?

Answer (score 0):

Without much info to go on, my only thought is that you are running in standards mode rather than [quirks mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode).

Try removing the doctype from your html to force the browser into quirks mode.

---

Directly upgrading from 1.2 or 1.5 to 2.4 is covering a lot of ground that may not be necessary.

Try an incremental approach that has documented changes within the community forums and stackoverflow.

1. first get your project stable & operational on the original GWT 1.2 or 1.5 version
2. then upgrade to latest 1.x release i.e. v1.7.1
3. then bump it to version 2.0

I am pretty sure v2.0 will run well on the latest IE9. If not, you can always bump the version to 2.4.
All the GWT SDK releases can co-exist within the same eclipse instance and are easy to download & install from [here](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/versions.html)

---

Within eclipse, you configure Web Toolkit SDK versions within this Preferences dialog tab.
click Window menu | Preferences | Google | Web Toolkit
[image: Web Toolkit SDK eclipse preferences]

Within the project, you specify the version of SDK using this dialog tab
right click project | Properties | 
[image: project settings]

After javac, Use this button to gwtc compile your application from java to js.
[image: happy toolkit button]

Comment: I tried with thi but nothong. Also the behaviour is down. I have this error: 18:02:33,532 http-8081-Processor20 ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/] - Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
javax.servlet.ServletException: Content-Type was 'text/plain; charset=utf-8'. Expected 'text/x-gwt-rpc'.

Comment: Ok, thanks! But, sorry, what means in practice change version? I have only to change the library in the lib dir? I have to recompile the project?

Comment: Perhaps you might want to practice first with the sample project and understand http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging.html